# How do I call .js from another .js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have mysql connection code which I need to call each time in every .js file. Say I want `sql.js` from `main.js`. I am thinking `include(sql.js)` ?

```
 sql.js

 var sql = require('sql');
 var connection = sql.createConnection({
 host : 'localhost',
 user : 'root',
 password : '',
 database : 'db'
 });

connection.connect(function(err){
if(!err) {
console.log("connected");
}
```

Comment: Please search before you ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry I did not include node whole searching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a module, and require it the following way.

File A: sql.js

```
var a = function a(){

};

module.exports.a = a;
```

Files B, C, D:

```
var sql = require("./sql");

sql.a();
```

Answer (score 0):

`require`.

for example  `var sql = require('sql.js');`

you need in the sql.js to return an object at the end with `module.exports = myobj`;

Example:

```
module.exports = {
 sql_connection: null,
 connect: function() {
    // connect to db
   this.sql_connection = ... ; // code to connect to the db
 }

};
```

Comment: In some scenarios, it is required to specify a path in the `require` function (i.e. './sql.js') in order to be recognized, as in @Pavel 's example

Comment: It depends if package.json is configured correctly i think, but yes if you don't use "./" it won't search in the current folder. It is better to use `require(__dirname + './script.js')` in order to execute the script from where you want.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant that is redundant. __dirname is the same as `./`. I don't code Js, so if that is the actual way they do it, then that's just one more reason to hate Js.