# PhantomJS - How to call file2.js from file1.js (by passing arguments from file1 to file2)

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am working with PhantomJS and have a file named `file1.js` which has the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
system = require('system');
var inputfile=system.args[1];
var stream = fs.open(inputfile,'r');
var data = stream.read(); 
var config = JSON.parse(data); 
var user_input=config.input;
var output_format=config.output;
stream.close();
```

The above code reads a JSON file and takes the `user_input` and `output_format` that were stored in the JSON file.

I have another file as well that is named as `file2.js` and now I want to call `file2.js` here from inside `file1.js` and want to pass both `user_input` and `output_format` as arguments.

The code of `file2.js` doesn't need to be added here.
The important thing is that `file1.js` should call `file2.js` and pass these two arguments to it. `file2.js` will then perform the required operations on those arguments.

I tried injectJS but it doesn't work since it only works with pages e.g. `page.injectJS`.
Also, injectJS only accepts one parameter which is a filename and nothing else. Thus, I am unable to achieve what I wanna achieve.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _calling a file_ in this context? Do you want to call a specific function from another file?

Comment: No, I want to call a complete file. See when code in file1.js completes execution, it should call file2.js so that it gets executed. but the code of file1.js should also pass parameters to file2.js while calling it.

Comment: Right. How would those passed parameters be received? How would they be used? Through environment variables or setting some globals by calling a function?

Comment: It could be anyway. I just want file1.js to pass parameters to file2.js while calling it. It doesn't matter which way it should be

Comment: There are multiple SO threads discussing the same thing. You need to look for them. Here's one approach that you use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36049001/7670262

Answer (score 0):

Just try this flow. may be it will help you

```
var page = require("webpage").create()
page.open(url, function () {
    page.includeJs(file1.js, function () {
        page.evaluate(function (params1, params2) {
            page.includeJs(file2.js, function () {
                page.evaluate(function (params3, params4) {
                    console.log(params3, param4)//this will print 10,20
                }, params1, params2)
            })
        }, 10, 20)
    })
})
```